# NotSupportedException when trying to use ffmpeg autogen

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the ffmpeg.autogen library, however no matter what function I call from it, I get a NotSupportedException.

I feel like I'm quite literally trying to do the bare minimum here:

```cs
using FFmpeg.AutoGen;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ffmpeg.RootPath = @"C:\Users\quent\source\repos\BulkVideoThumbnailTest\BulkVideoThumbnailTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\FFmpeg\bin\x64";
    Console.WriteLine(ffmpeg.av_version_info());
}
```

The directory I set RootPath to does indeed contain avcodec-59.dll, avdevice-59.dll, avformat-59.dll, avutil-57.dll, swresample-4.dll and swscale-6.dll.

Am I missing something here..? According to a [github example](https://github.com/stjeong/ffmpeg_autogen_cs/blob/master/decode_video/Program.cs), it seems there shouldn't be anything else needed for it to run, atleast not to just get the version info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by using an FFMpeg.Autogen version prior to 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and I solved it!

1. Check version of   ffmpeg.autogen , ffmpeg
2. Check path - Try putting it in the `D:\ffmpeg`